# How to pass parent element id as parameter to function on ng-change

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

```html
 <ul class="nav" id="usrList">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" id={{user.uid}} name={{$index}} 
        ng-click="fillUserForm($event)">{{user.mobile + " / " + user.email}} 
      <input type="checkbox" style="float:right;" ng-model="usersCheck[$index]" 
           ng-change="activeInactiveUser($parent.attribute.id,usersCheck[$index])" 
           ng-checked="usersCheck[$index]" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

how to get parent element id to pass it in **`activeInactiveUser(parent id,"")`** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-init for it, because it is verbose and improves readability:

```
<ul class="nav" id="usrList">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index" id={{user.uid}} name={{$index}} 
        ng-click="fillUserForm($event)">{{user.mobile + " / " + user.email}} 
      <input type="checkbox" style="float:right;" ng-model="usersCheck[$index]" 
           ng-change="activeInactiveUser(sectionIndex.uid,usersCheck[$index])" 
           ng-checked="usersCheck[$index]" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually i wants user.uid as id in function. Finally i got this just by little change in your answer ng-init="sectionIndex = user.id".

Comment: Thanks buddy. @Shota.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought you needed parent $index, anyway glad you get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass `user.uid` to the function `activeInactiveUser`

```
 <ul class="nav" id="usrList">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" id={{user.uid}} name={{$index}} 
        ng-click="fillUserForm($event)">{{user.mobile + " / " + user.email}} 
      <input type="checkbox" style="float:right;" ng-model="usersCheck[$index]" 
           ng-change="activeInactiveUser(user.uid, usersCheck[$index])" 
           ng-checked="usersCheck[$index]" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post your usrList array in question.